# How to set value in unbounded cell of bound datagrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have bound datagrid on wpf window. I have added an unbounded column and want to set value in that on any event. How can I do this?

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="delFlgColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=DelFlg,  NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Del Flg" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ModeFlgColumn" Header="Mode" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Visible"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to set "D" in ModeFlgColumn where user checks the checkbox delFlgColumn. so how can i do this?

Comment: please add some code, showing your effort

Answer (score 0):

Modify your xaml to the following

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
        x:Name="delFlgColumn" 
        Binding="{Binding Path=DelFlg, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Header="Del Flg" 
        Width="SizeToHeader" 
        Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
        x:Name="ModeFlgColumn" 
        Header="Mode" 
        Width="SizeToHeader" 
        Visibility="Visible" 
        YourEvent="YourEventMethod"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

In codebehind add this method

```
private void YourEventMethod(object sender, YourEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I want to set "D" in ModeFlgColumn where user checks the checkbox delFlgColumn. so how can i do this?

Comment: Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx